# Need a fast alternative to Java TreeMap<Integer, Character> that can hold many mappings without slowdown

Tags: java, object, primitive, treemap, sorting

I am writing a Java program that uses a TreeMap and the performance slows down to a crawl once there are 10's of thousands of integer, character mappings.

I was wondering if there is an implementation of some type of sorted set implementation out there that can use the int and char primitives and has something like the "headMap" and "tailMap" functions.

I am looking at Trove currently.  I also looked at an implementation of a linked list that uses an insertion sort but didn't include the head and tail functions.  I think a linked list with an insertion sort would be slower than a tree, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: If the map is dense then you might be able to use Arrays and use the key as index into the array.

Comment: A TreeMap of integers to characters should be fast. What exactly is slow? inserting? Can you post some example code?

Comment: I really can't tell which portion is slow.  The program is gigantic and I need to use a code profiler.  I tried eclipse TPTP and it is crap (see post 7664785 ).

Comment: I have had good success identifying hotspots in large system by using AspectJ for tracing instead of a full profiler.

Comment: Genetic algorithm, except the "genetic sequence" for each of the organisms in the population is mostly the same; so instead of storing an entire sequence in each organism, there is a "global reference sequence"; each individual has a TreeMap storing its differences from this sequence: the positions of the differences, and the character to be used in place of the reference sequence.  It is an enormous program, is there some way I can upload it?

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you could tell us the approximate ratio of inserts to lookups.

Comment: I agree with @JimGarrison, and also if you really need to have an ordering over the keys.

Comment: 10s of thousands of int->char mappings shouldn't be "slow", since operations are proportional to log2(n) (i.e. for 100,000 elements that's ~17 lookups on average per lookup). The only way I see this being "slow" is if you are running out of memory.

Comment: To verify the idea that you are running out of memory, try running your test with a as large `Xmx` setting as you can get away and see the timing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a replacement for something like `TreeMap<Integer,Character>` and if your integer keys are dense then an array would be most efficient. But it woud be a `char[]` instead of an `int[]` because you want to lookup the `char`depending on the `int`-key.
Then I read something about 'genome'?! Supposed that you want to use `char` to represent the  Adenin, Guanin, Cytosin and Thymin (I'm not an expert for that) remember that `char` takes you 16 bit each - far more than you need for four different things. Perhaps you can do with somenthing like

```
...
public static final byte UNDEF = (byte)-1;
public static final byte ADENIN = 0;
public static final byte GUANIN = 1;
public static final byte CYTOSIN = 2;
public static final byte THYMIN = 3;
...
private byte[] genome = new byte[ 26000000 ]; // or which size ever
...
```

And if this still eats up too much memory, it would become tricky: Suppose you don't need the `UNDEF` value you would only need 2 bits for the four values, i.e. one could store your sequence with four values per byte ending up with need for about 6.5 MB. But for such things you need to do some bit-fiddeling...

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question, you want a data structure that preserves the order of the keys, that is, the position of the char that replaces the one in the reference sequence for an individual.

I am assuming that you process the items by increasing position order.

Now, since a TreeMap is implementing a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), it has logarithmic complexity for the basic operations.

If you just need to iterate the sequence in order, you are taking a serious performance hit on each insert.

**If my assumptions are correct**, I would say you may use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

As the javadoc explains:

> This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally
>   chaotic ordering provided by HashMap (and Hashtable), without
>   incurring the increased cost associated with TreeMap.

Meaning that you can iterate over your elements in the same order you entered them, but the basic operations have the same complexity as a normal HashMap, with a performance hit due to the linked list handling.

You may picture this as an HashMap traversed by a double-linked list connecting the keys in the order they were inserted.

Please note that I am not addressing the fact that your sequence fits in memory or not. Also, be aware that a LinkedHashMap will take more memory than a simple HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

One technique that works with very large sorted maps is to use a combination of a SortedSet to manage your keys in sorted order, and a Map to manage the actual key to value mapping. In this way you can do quick iterations of the keys using headSet() and tailSet(), and then use the keys returned from the set to look up the actual map.

I have no evidence for why this work, but in my experience is is 10x faster with very large sorted maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a faster Map implementation, have you considered [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? This still uses objects but if initially created (see the third form of the constructor in the previous link) with a large enough capacity this would allow for much faster access to your data than a `TreeMap`.

Alternatively if you only interested in SortedSet-like behavior in your map, you may be able to get better performance using [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

As for Trove, I am not familiar with it but I suspect that you can get significant performance  enhancements out of the Java provided classes rather than resorting to 3rd party libs with only the little extra effort of examining what is is you need out of your data structures and what extra work is being wasted by them providing features you don't need.

Comment: Right, there is a key-value pairing.  I used TreeSet before this was a requirement.  Tried Trove... no good, need a data type that is sorted upon insertion of an element

Comment: TreeSet uses a TreeMap under the hood, it can't possibly be faster.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve writes it may be worthwhile checking using a profiler that the TreeMap is the culprit.

A couple of other options are:

- Use a `HashMap` with large `initialCapacity`
- If your keyset is dense then you can use an `int[]`. That will be fastest.

Comment: problem with int[] is that the range of values is between 0 and 26 million.  writing genetic algorithm with genome of 26M characters and each individual has mutations stored in treemap.

Comment: Array size 26M may not be too much memory. If you need to iterate over valid values then you will have to augment the data structure. If you only need indexed access then arrays might be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at the PriorityQueue?
it has some useful method and sorts elements depending on the comparator you define .

Comment: How will that help in this case?

Comment: i just found out that it won't help in this case .. sorry i missunderstood the problem. my appologies

Answer (score 0):

To hold huge number of elements youd better use [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). This kind of structures are widely used in data bases to hold indexes. For example on Oracle and MySQL, if Iam not mistaken. have a look at [JDBM3](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3). There also should exist other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is your performance bottleneck and/or memory problem - then I'd consider using the trove `TIntCharHashMap`. I've used the trove maps to increase performance and decrease memory consumption quite successfully in the past.

Note that the keys will not be sorted, but you can get to a `int[]` for the keys quite cheaply, which you can then sort. So if you only need sorted traversal occasionally you can sort them as required.

If you find that ugly (or performance impeding) you can wrap the `TIntCharHashMap` and sorted `int[]` into your own sorted map - you'll just need to maintain the invariant yourself.

I find it a little unfortunate that trove does not directly tree-based order-maintaining map/set classes, but am thankful for the tools it does provide.

Answer (score 0):

It worth to try [B-Tree](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2016/12/29/faster-ordered-maps-for-java/) like solution by Max Bolingbroke.